# Retrieving UINavigationController Properties from child UIViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, properties, uinavigationcontroller, subclass

I have created a subclass of `UINavigationController` called `CustomNavigationController` which tracks the level the user is currently on.

It has a property called `currentLevel`, of type `NSString`.

```
// CustomNavigationController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController{
    NSString *_currentLevel;
}    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *currentLevel;
@end
```

I'm able to retrieve the property from the child View Controllers with the following:

```
[(CustomNavigationController *)self.navigationController currentLevel];
```

However, the currentLevel always returns `(null)`.

I've referenced a setter method in my view controllers which increments it:

```
[(CustomNavigationController *)self.navigationController setCurrentLevel:@"Level 5"];
NSLog(@"%@",[(CustomNavigationController *)self.navigationController currentLevel]);
//returns Level 5
```

However, when a new view controller is pushed onto the stack, or popped from the stack, my original line in the `viewDidLoad` method returns `(null)`.

There's going to be a particular type of `ViewController` contained within my `CustomNavigationController`. This View Controller depends on knowing what level it's on. I have logic to return a particular result depending on what level the user is currently viewing on the `CustomNavigationController`.

Comment: The second method you listed should work, assuming you're navigationController is the subclass (i.e. you're manually creating the correct subclass in code or in the XIB). It'd be worth showing your code in the subclass as that's likely to be the error. I can't help but think this could be solved with a more elegant solution however, what's your intended use of the currentLevel property?

Comment: @InsertWittyName I've updated my question which will hopefully help you understand my thinking.

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried checking the currentLevel in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad? Also, you could get the currentLevel without the subclassed navigation controller by doing something like: NSUInteger level = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self];

Comment: @InsertWittyName it's not an integer anymore, it's a string representation - Something like "Introduction Level" - "Rookie Level" - "Intermediate Level" etc.

Comment: You could use an enum to represent that as an integer and do a switch or similar to create a string representation of it when needed with hardly any effort.